# execute .sql script inside an anonymous pl/sql block which is invoked by a shell script

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, scripting

I got a shell script which connects to SQLPLUS and executes the .sql file like below:

```
 read a
 x=`echo $a | cut -d , -f 1`
 y=`echo $a | sed 's/.*,//'`
 c=`echo $USER | cut -c -2`"OPR"`echo $USER | cut -c 6-`
 sqlplus -s `echo $c`/`echo $c`@$OPERATIONAL_DB_NAME @dbl.sql $x $y
```

Below is the SQL (dbl.sql)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
x varchar2(100):='&&1';
y varchar2(100):='&&2';
BEGIN
execute immediate 'CREATE DATABASE LINK  SSS_DBL CONNECT TO ' || x || ' IDENTIFIED BY ' || x || ' USING ''' || y || '''';
@1_a.sql
@1_b.sql
@1_c.sql
END;
/
EXIT;
```

In the above sql, 1_a.sql,1_b.sql,1_c.sql are three sql files in which there are a set of insert statements, taking the data from a remote db, using the link created
above.

Now, I can not run these sql's inside the pl/sql block using @ symbol as written above. What is the other way to do this? If I use 3 procedures for each insert files, then, should
these procedures be run and compiled before using in this pl/sql, in each session or how should I use these?
I want to keep this script as independent of any session or db.

Comment: Why not just move the `@...` lines _after_ the PL/SQL block?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked fine with the first insert script, but it is taking only the first insert script and not executing the second and third, but exits. Could you please tell me what I should do in order to consider all the separate insert sql files ?

Comment: I believe you want to use `@@1_a.sql` instead of `@1_a.sql` etc.

Comment: Hi..I tried with @@, still only the first sql is being taken, and it exits from SQL. Could you please suggest?

Comment: Do you have 'exit' on the last line of those scripts? if so, remove them.

Comment: I don't have exit in the end of these 3 script files....still it doesn't move to the second and third files.

Comment: Maybe you could add `SET ECHO ON` at the top of your SQL file so that you can see in the output whether it ever tries to call `@1_b.sql`?  Could you edit the question and include the text of a sample `1_a.sql` file  (after scrubbing out any sensitive/proprietary info)?  You could also add debugging lines like `PROMPT About to run first script`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Below is the sample insert statements in the .sql files: Insert into BLAAA select * from BLAAA@SSS_DBL;
insert into BLBBB select * from BLBBB@SSS_DBL;
insert into BLCCC select * from BLCCC@SSS_DBL;         There are around 25-30 insert statements in each of the 3 .sql files, I am trying to insert into the tables of one instance, taking the insert statements from the other, thru' the dblink which has been created in the above pl/sql block. Could you please tell me what can be changed to consider all three sql's?

Comment: Did you write the 3 scripts outside a PL/SQL and finishing each sentence with a ;?